# Search pagination using PHP and PDO

Tags: php, search, pdo, pagination

I would like to make a pagination for the results of the searched entry.

I already tried some codes that paginates data but it's not working on search.

On the first page, it's fine. It's showing first 20 results and has the right pagination and total result. But whenever I click next or forward, it shows "no results could be displayed" which means the entry that was entered got lost.

Please help. Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");//databaseconnection
$entry = $_POST['entry'];
    // Find out how many items are in the table
    $total = $dbconn->query('
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            'mytable'
        WHERE
            'column' = $entry
    ')->fetchColumn();

    // How many items to list per page
    $limit = 20;

    // How many pages will there be
    $pages = ceil($total / $limit);

    // What page are we currently on?
    $page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
        'options' => array(
            'default'   => 1,
            'min_range' => 1,
        ),
    )));

    // Calculate the offset for the query
    $offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;

    // Some information to display to the user
    $start = $offset + 1;
    $end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);

    // The "back" link
    $prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="?page=1" title="First page">&laquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page">&lsaquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';

    // The "forward" link
    $nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Next page">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page">&raquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';

    // Display the paging information
    echo '<div id="paging"><p>', $prevlink, ' Page ', $page, ' of ', $pages, ' pages, displaying ', $start, '-', $end, ' of ', $total, ' results ', $nextlink, ' </p></div>';

    // Prepare the paged query
    $stmt = $dbconn->prepare('
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            'mytable'
        WHERE
            'column' = $entry
        LIMIT
            :limit
        OFFSET
            :offset
    ');

    // Bind the query params
    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Do we have any results?
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        // Define how we want to fetch the results
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $iterator = new IteratorIterator($stmt);

        // Display the results
        foreach ($iterator as $row) {
            echo $row['ID'] . ", " . $row['name'] . "<br>";
        }

    } else {
        echo '<p>No results could be displayed.</p>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: You have to add search text to `$_GET` param when clicking another page e.g. `index.php?page=2&search=something`

Answer (score 0):

When your **link** is clicked `$entry` will be empty as there is no POST request made and thus `$entry = $_POST['entry'];` is empty (link click uses GET method). You need to alter this to either use GET or use **form** with `method="post"` for your pagination.